# Validating email address in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to validate an email address user has entered. I've done the validation in model but its not working. I have used the following in model...

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  validates_presence_of :emp_name_official
  validates_presence_of :emp_name_full
  validates_format_of :emp_email_personal, :with=>/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message=>"Not a valid email format"
end
```

I am using version 2.0.2 of rails.

And it works fine when I comment the validation line in my model. And also works fine when I give correct email address.

Can anyone tell where I am going wrong.

Following is the error page.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean it is not working?

Comment: I am getting an error of method not found in my view while creating new employee. Although it is giving error on some other line but by commenting this email validation all things work fine. So, I think problem might be in email validation line. I am newbie to RoR and don't get much of its idea.

Comment: Does the `emp_email_personal` field exists in the database schema?

Comment: What method is not found? Copy the entire stack trace into your question

Comment: OK... I am editing my question and paste the whole page.

Comment: And one more thing. When I pass correct email format it works fine. but When I pass wrong email address it throws the above mentioned error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  EmailRegex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates_format_of :email, :with => EmailRegex
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just sorted out. It is the problem with my all the validations. If any validation fails, It throws the above no method error. I'll work on it why this sort of error is coming. I'll open a separate question for it.

Thanks to all of you for all responses and directions.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something to do with the trialling 'i' after your regex?

Comment: I just copied this regex from google search. Most of the people use this.